# mongoDB: adding and updating some fields in a (nested) object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is a mongoDB document, to which I need to add some data:

```
{
    "_id" : "7KufvMQFyyeuKFP68",
    "target" : {
        "10" : "true",
        "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
    }
}
```

I need to update existing fields in `target` or add them, if they do not exist. This is what I tried:

```
var result = { "30": "true", "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM" };

Collection.upsert(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $set: { target: result } }
);
```

But with this `10` is replaced by `30`, but I expect this result:

```
{
    "_id" : "7KufvMQFyyeuKFP68",
    "target" : [{
        "10" : "true",
        "30" : "true",
        "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Mongo upserts the whole `result` document.For partial upsertion you need to have multiple upsert for each column.

Comment: In the original document target is not an array is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want an array of objects to be updated. The array is your `target` field so make sure the type is an array in your schema. To update the array select the array by the id or field of your choice.

This code finds the field and adds the `"30" : "true",` and leaves the other information in the object inside an array. Hope it helps.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    target : []
})
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
//creat a documenent 

var user1 = new User({
    name : "jack",
    target :[{
        "10" : "true",
        "id" : "ePce6fBAHx9KeKjuM"
    }]
})
user1.save(user1, function(err, user){
    console.log(user)
})
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"name" : "jack"},
    {safe : true, upsert : true, new :true},
    function(err, model){
        model.target[0]["30"] = "true"
        console.log(model.target)
    }
)
```